# Why are movies released only on Friday in India?

Tags: distribution, indian-cinema

In India, both Bollywood and Hollywood movies are released in cinema hall only on Friday. What is the reason?

What I think is that because after Friday you have two days of weekend holiday (Saturday and Sunday) to enjoy the movie.

Comment: Friday followed by 2 days weekend. So, the probability of people who watch movies will be more on these two days so the makers can get good amount of money in early days

Comment: Friday is a holiday for people in tertiary sector

Answer (score 25):

The same question was [asked to *The Times of India*](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/home/sunday-times/Why-are-films-released-only-on-Friday/articleshow/24287259.cms) and the answer by Jayant Mukherjee was: (emphasis added)

> The release of films in India follows the American style. **There a film is released on Friday so that people can watch the film with their family during the work-free weekends (Saturday and Sunday) leading to good opening collection.**

So it's not an India-only thing, we picked up this method from western countries.

From [ScoopWhoop](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/Why-Movies-Release-On-Friday/#.gvlpc1ukk):

> However, the trend of releasing movies on a Friday didn't start in India until the late 1950s. Neel Kamal released on 24th March, 1947, which was a Monday. Mughal-E-Azam was among the first movies to be released on 5th August, 1960, a Friday. So we ended up adopting the British/American legacy after all, in the late 1950s.
>
> Also, Friday is considered as the day of goddess Lakshmi in India. So, releasing movies on Friday came from the belief that producers would be blessed with good wealth.

Comment: Note that the opening day is not the same in all countries. In France, movies open on Wednesday.

Comment: In Germany, it's Thursday, although some movies have worldwide synchronized releases. In the past, it also used to be that it took months until a movie was released in Germany, but nowadays it seems that dubbing is accelerated (or rather the American release delayed) so that the movie can be released in all major localized markets in the same week.

Comment: *"The screening fee that producers have to pay to multiplex owners is higher for days other than Friday."* Why? How much?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, simultaneous release is a piracy mitigation exercise

Comment: The reality is also that these "set" days are often ignored for major releases via avant-premieres etc.

Comment: What 'screening fee'? Exhibitors pay rentals to the distributor. Not the other way round.

Comment: @Separatrix And also reasonable in widely-connected modern societies. It's easy to get spoiled on a movie that came out a month before in another country.